# Call Rest service from Spring Integration without invoking from MVC container

Tags: spring-integration

A program fetches the data from database and send to JMS queue using Spring Integration and call the POST rest service.

Now the question is if we use HTTP:INBOUND ADAPTER to call the rest service, we may need to use through the servlet container. But i don't a war file application. I need another feasible approach where we call the REST service from Spring Integration,as my program is a standalone program.

Comment: Your app calls rest service? Should it  be Outbound-gateway?

Comment: You are right.But if we put this queue data is send through outbound adapter.It should be as HTTP outbound adapter.The challenge here is it should be configured in servlet.Since we have standalone app, it is not possible.

Comment: I planned to use the jms:outbound adapter and call the rest service through the rest client.Hope this will resolve my requirment.

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time; we are looking at various options for a stand-alone ReST solution.